# Самовольное перенаправление страницы WordPress

Tags: wordpress

WordPress редиректит со страницы `/faq/` на главную. Если переименовать `slug` на другой, то нормально работает.

1. В шаблонах редирект не использовал;
2. Плагины пробовал отключал;
3. `.htaccess` удалял;
4. кеш чистил.

Подскажите где ещё можно ковырять, чтобы вернуть странице предназначенный `slug`?
Такое начало происходить, как создал некоторое кол-во кастомных постов. В них перебрал, ничего ломающего не нашёл.

Comment: Если редирект был, вы его убрали, то нужно почистить кеш

Comment: @Krya кеш чистил, не помогло

Comment: Cтраница `/faq/` не прописана как `На главной странице отображать`->`Статическую страницу (выберите ниже)`->`Главная страница` ?

Comment: @br3t да, стоит главная страница

Comment: Собственно, потому и редирект. Вам же не нужна одна и та же страница, доступная по двум адресам?

Comment: @br3t а нет, главная страница использует slug: /sample-page/. По этому uri не пройти. Страницу /faq/ удалил, по идее должна 404 ошибка. Но все-равно редиректит

Comment: Какой то СЕО плагин не стоит случайно у вас на сайте (типа Yoast SEO), обычно такие плагины создают редиректы?

Comment: Очисть корзину, кеши, хтацесс. Проверь наличие этого слага у других постов/страниц. В конце-концов по базе поищи где засветился. Редирект проверяй сторонними сервисами

Comment: @VitaliyAntal сео плагинов нет

Comment: @SeVlad скиньте пожалуйста ссылку сервиса?

Comment: @ВиталийБриль https://bertal.ru/